# Do I need SSL/TLS for TCP

Tags: tls, network, http, tcp

It might sound stupid but I could not find the straight answer.

1. Do I need to worry about communication security if I use only TCP socket to communicate between 2 machines? Is the byte stream can be intercepted and read in plain?
2. Do I need to SSL/TLS if I am not using application-level protocol(HTTP)?
3. If 2 Yes, then how to that in C++/C.

Comment: 1: yes, 2: yes, 3: that's very broad

Comment: Is the byte stream encrypted? Do you need encryption at all?

Comment: @schroeder: No, but I can encrypt it If I want. If I encrypt SSL/TLS not required ?.

Comment: Why do you assume there is *any* layer where exchanging confidential information wouldn't require encryption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that yes, if you want secure communication using TCP you need to either implement application-level security or use SSL/TLS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol and see the right hand side of the page for a description of the different layers. TCP is on a fundamentally different layer than TLS/SSL.

As to how to do that in C or C++, that depends largely on what you're trying to accomplish and is too broad a question.

Comment: But I'm not going beyond TCP layer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What is the "But" in response to? You're not going beyond in which direction - higher or lower?

Comment: Assume my endpoints and applications are secure. Can some man-in-middle attack can happen if I don't use SSL.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.